# AWS- SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER - Elastic Load Balancing

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, https, aws-application-load-balancer

I have an EC2 Instance with an Load Balancer(ELB), this Load Balancer have a certificate and my Route53 is forwarding to this loadbalancer.
On the EC2 only runs a node.js backend.

Now i have two problems:
1.) After i add my instance the status is "OutOfService"
[image]

2.) I can connect with the Backend per http:// but not with https://.
I was sure it works with the ELB and the certificate.

Stacktrace:

> Error: write EPROTO 3181765672:error:100000f7:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER:../../third_party/boringssl/src/ssl/tls_record.cc:242:

LoadBalancing Health Check:[image: HealthCheck]

[image: Listeners]

Do you have some tipps?

Best regards

Comment: Hi, did you intentionally placed a SSL certificate on the EC2 instances? could you share the target group and listener settings?

Comment: Hi, no. And EC2 instance cant handle the AWS- Certificate. I can use maybe lets encrypt and nginx on my ec2 instance, but i want to handle all with AWS to try it out

Comment: How are you sending the traffic to the EC2? Are you targeting a HTTPS or HTTP endpoint on the EC2?

Comment: @Tobay your ELB  health check is configured on which port and protocol ? If you add a https listener on ELB you can select the cert from ACM

Comment: Yes i target it on HTTPS in the ECS. I send it from an amplify frontend via rest. 

@Error404 yes i select the cert from the ADM

Comment: I think you should test by configuring your HC at TCP 80/443 and then hit the server directly using https endpoint with the cert being hosted on ec2 instance using nginx

Comment: Maybe i have to use another instance of load balancer ? I use classic, maybe its the wrong one?